# Does serving a directory page as "not found" affect SEO of its sub pages?

Tags: seo, google-ranking, directory

If my site has pages of form:

- `/product_root/product1`
- `/product_root/product2`
- `/product_root/product3`

If somehow my page `/product_root/ gets served as "404 Not Found" to Googlebot, would rankings of my above product pages also gets affected?

Is it mandatory to have this page the root page on my site or can I directly have the product URLs without it?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how your products are internally linked. If the only way the crawler can get them, is through product_root - then they will be affected too. If crawler has other link pathes to products (and will go them) - then ok.

Comment: The product_root was well indexed and cached. Due to some temporary error the crawler cached it as 404, and our rankings fall at same time from 1, 2 to 3 4 ranks. That made us think that it might be due to the wrong indexing of product_root. Also the products are reachable through sitemap as well as a listing page link present in footer of other pages. So what is your take on this ?

Comment: look into server logs: whether they were indeed  visited by googlebot?